# Creating a Y_true Dataset in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here's my current call to model.fit in Keras

```
history_callback = model.fit(x_train/255.,
                             validation_train_data,
                             validation_split=validation_split,
                             batch_size=batch_size,
                             callbacks=callbacks)
```

in this example `x_train` is a list of numpy arrays that contains all of my image data. The way `validation_train_data` is structured though is its a list of numpy arrays of totally different sizes that is equal in length to the list of numpy arrays that contains my image. The data for each image though is contained in validation_train_data such that `x_train[i]` would correspond to a set containing `validation_train_data[0][i]`, `validation_train_data[1][i]`, `validation_train_data[2][i]`, etc. Is there any way I can reformat my validation_train_data such that it can properly be used as a `y_true` in a custom keras loss function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by writing a generator function which generated a batch of x and y data as lists and put them together as a tuple. I then called fit_generator with the argument where generator = my_generator and it worked just fine. If you have odd input data then you should consider writing a generator to take care of it.

This is the tutorial I used to do so:
https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly